# Mapping musicbrainz URIs into Spotify URIs

Tags: spotify, musicbrainz

Does anybody know how can I find Spotify's URI for a given artist/album's musicbrainz URI? Spotify's web-api doesn't solve my problem cause I wanna map all the musicbrainz artists and albums and it's quite slow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the Echo Nest Rosetta Stone Project to map Spotify and MusicBrainz artist ids: http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4

Comment: Yeah, it solves mapping artist ids, any idea about albums mapping?

Comment: We expose our IDs for artists. You'll have to check with Musicbrainz.

Comment: this API has been deprecated since 2016 after Echo Nest was acquired by Spotify. The Spotify artist API doesn't have similar functionality, unfortunately.