# How to retrieve all album objects on Spotify?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

Looking at the Spotify API and spotipy, I am able to pull album information as long as I have the album ID or a list of album IDs, but how can I pull all album objects on Spotify in an efficient manner? I think this would require knowing all album IDs, but unsure if there is a method to get that.

**Purpose**:
I want to see the number of tracks for all albums on Spotify

**Potential idea**

1) Inspired by [Mapping musicbrainz URIs into Spotify URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462343/mapping-musicbrainz-uris-into-spotify-uris), I could map Music Brainz artist IDs to Spotify IDs which would cover a good amount of the artists on Spotify. Then pull album data from there. Issue is that Echo Nest Rosetta Stone is no longer supported

Is there a much easier way to do this that I'm not thinking about or is this impossible to do because Spotify doesn't allow it?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, it should be possible to [query](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/#writing-a-query---guidelines) with `type=album` and `q=a*`, `q=b*`, `q=c*`, etc. The **Wildcards** guildlines says

> The asterisk (*) character can, with some limitations, be used as a wildcard (maximum: 2 per query) [...] It cannot be used: [...] as the first character of the keyword string Field filters: By default, results are returned when a match is found in any field of the target object type.

hence why I'm using `a*` and the rest. That said,

1. There are almost certain a *lot* of albums, and it'll be difficult to store so many
2. It's probably a violation of their ToS to store their catalog
3. Although it's reasonable, it's not a given that album IDs are immutable/will exist in any future capacity, so associating them externally might break in the future

Side note: it's deeper than Echo Nest not being supported -- Spotify *bought* Echo Nest several years ago. Algorithms they produced form the backbone of their audio analysis.